# Kendo UI Grid Editor Template Ajax Drop Down displays value field not text field

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I've got a hierarchical Kendo UI Grid (MVC Server Helpers) where one of the columns is a FK lookup that is backed with an Editor Template that does an AJAX lookup for the values.  All of that works perfectly.  What's not working is the column is showing the ID (Data Value Field from the drop down) and not the text (Data Text Field from the drop down).

Here's the Grid

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ReceivingLogItemResponse>()
        .Name("grid_#=GID#")
        .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .Sortable()
        .Columns( c=>
            {
                c.Bound(i => i.GID).Hidden();
                c.Bound(i => i.SerialNumber);
                c.Bound(i => i.PartNumber);
                c.Bound(i => i.Description);
                c.Bound(i => i.Quantity);
                c.Bound(i => i.ItemLotNumber).Title("Lot");
                c.Bound(i => i.StatusId).Title("Status");
                c.Bound(i => i.CategoryId).EditorTemplateName("ClientCategory");
                c.Bound(i => i.LocationCode).Title("Location");
                c.Bound(i => i.Comments);
                c.Command(e => e.Custom("Add").Click("doItemAdd"));
            })
            .ToolBar(t => t.Save())
        .Selectable(s => s.Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .WebApi()
            .Model(m => 
                {
                    m.Id(i => i.GID);
                    m.Field(i => i.GID).Editable(false);
                })
            .Batch(true)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Read(read => read.Url(apiWrapper.receivingLogItemUrl() + "&receivingLogId=#=GID#").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
            .Update(u => u.Url(apiWrapper.receivingLogItemUpdateUrl()).Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
        )
        .Events(e => e.DataBound("itemDataBound"))
        .ToClientTemplate()
)
```

And here's the EditorTemplate (ClientCategory)

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Name("CategoryId")
.DataTextField("Code")
.DataValueField("CID")
.AutoBind(true)
.DataSource(ds => ds.Read(a => a.Url(apiWrapper.clientCategoryUrl()).Data("getClientCategoryID()"))))
```

The column displays the CID field until you enter it for editing, when the drop-down shows up it's populated with the correct values.  When you go to another field it goes back to the CID.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. Have you solved this?